# Get "No such file or directory" when testing on iPad device but not in simulator

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

I have an app that i am release as iPhone and iPad even if it developed as Universal. The reason is that i have release an English version that is Universal and just want to update the iPhone and iPad Swedish versions as it have been with separate apps for the different devices.

When i run on the iPhone device i have no problems but when testing with iPad i get the message below, which i do not know how to remove:

> "Could not launch “FamilyQuiz_3"
>
> > No such file or directory (/Users/peterk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp_3-fosmfwberzyfryenqrjlfpacftjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp_3.app/MyApp_3)

I can start the app from the iPad device but it do not start automatically when submit from XCODE.

Comment: Check uppercase/lowercase file names.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1)make sure your **iOS Deployment Target** version is the same or lower than the one on your device in build settings.

2)delete it from the device

3)close xcode

4)Goto /Users/peterk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ on your computer and delete the 
MyApp_3-fosmfwberzyfryenqrjlfpacftjv folder

if that still doesnt work go and try deleting the app restarting your phone, and then restarting your computer even, and doing it again.