# Xcode app not run in device

Tags: ios

I got this error message in Xcode 4.5.2:

```
Could not launch “TestApp”

No such file or directory (~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestApp-dvmrmbairhacdcehjotrsbsxwiob/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TestApp.app/TestApp) .
```

I follow the following step but no success:

- Deleted my DerivedData directory (emptied trash too)
- Quit XCode
- Disconnected iPad USB
- Rebooted Mac
- Rebooted iPad (power down and back up)
- Reconnected iPad USB.
- Restarted Xcode with project
- Confirmed build for debug on device selected.
- Clicked Run

Actually I copy this project from any other system. 
I also check the bundle identifier - it is OK. And Project run sccessfullly in Simulator but not in iPhone device.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12665360/get-no-such-file-or-directory-when-testing-on-ipad-device-but-not-in-simulator

Comment: @MilKyWaY Agreed. Well known problem that easily could have been answered if humza searched for "could not launch" and "no such file or directory".

Answer (score 2):

[image]Check your developer certificate !

Comment: All are correct still no scussess. Any other idea any one